# Pytorch - Custom DataLoader runs forever

Tags: pytorch

```
class TripletImageLoader(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [0]*10000000

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        pid = os.getpid() % WORKER_SIZE
        # My code here only uses pid, doesnt use index

        return torch.tensor(batch.data), torch.tensor(batch.label)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)
```

I need my data loader to run forever. Right now it always terminates after hitting 10000000 or whatever the max integer size is. How do i make this run forever, I dont care about 'index' I am not using it. I am simply using the worker capabilities of this class

Comment: What do you mean data loader runs forever? data loader is usually used to load data and generate mini-batches. Why do you want to run it forever?

Comment: i need it to train over the same batch again several times

Comment: Yes, we, in general, do the same. Just run a loop over the number of training epochs.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to train over the same batch for several iterations, the following code skeleton should work for you.

```
def train(args, data_loader):
    for idx, ex in enumerate(data_loader):
        # iterate over each mini-batches
        # add your code

def validate(args, data_loader):
     with torch.no_grad():
        for idx, ex in enumerate(data_loader):
            # iterate over each mini-batches
            # add your code

# args = dict() containing required parameters
for epoch in range(start_epoch, args.num_epochs):
    # train_loader = data loader for the training data
    train(args, train_loader)
```

You can have the data loader as follows.

```
class ReaderDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, examples):
        # examples = a list of examples
        # add your code

    def __len__(self):
        # return total dataset size

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # write your code to return each batch item

train_dataset = ReaderDataset(train_examples)
train_sampler = torch.utils.data.sampler.RandomSampler(train_dataset)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        train_dataset,
        batch_size=args.batch_size,
        sampler=train_sampler,
        num_workers=args.data_workers,
        collate_fn=batchify,
        pin_memory=args.cuda,
        drop_last=args.parallel
    )
# batchify is a custom function to prepare the mini-batches
```